# Condition on coefficients of a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

We express a linear equation in two variables as: $a x + b y + c = 0$, where $a$ and $b$ both are not simultaneously equal to zero.

That is, if $a\neq 0, b$ can be zero and vice versa but not $a=b=0$.

Can anybody please mention how to write this condition on $a$ and $b$ concisely in mathematical notations?

I'm a complete novice to stackexchange, so if anyone finds this question too fundamental, please suggest where to ask it?

Comment: $$a^2+b^2\not=0$$ If you need both are non-zero, try $ab\not=0.$

Comment: No , question here is fundamental as long as you have put some effort to it. As you can see even "algebra precalculus" tag exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

This would work
$$
\lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert \ne 0
$$
Note: I see Nilan used a similar expression in the comments.

This would work as well
$$
\neg (a = 0 \wedge b = 0) = a \ne 0 \vee b \ne 0
$$